# How to get information that youtube video is blocked on mobile

Tags: android, youtube-api

I do YouTube Data API search and get these videos:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QC2Grms55Fw
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dASqLXiuomY

But android devices do not show them due restriction.

Is it possible to detect this restriction via YouTube Data API? Which property display this?

Comment: Please show some code and explain what exactly isn't working.

Comment: It works for me too, would that be because of your location?

Comment: On personal computer it works fine for me on any of browser. But i can not play them on android device. Youtube player display:  "This video is not available", mobile browser - "This video is not playable". My country is not blocked by location.

Answer (score 0):

According to the API v3 reference, the `contentDetails` part of a video resource has the `regionRestriction` property. See [the reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.regionRestriction) for details.

For your example videos, the API reveals the following:

```
"contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT5M5S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "hd",
    "caption": "true",
    "licensedContent": false,
    "regionRestriction": {
        "blocked": [
            "DE"
        ]
    }
}
```

Germany is the only country these videos are blocked in.

Blöde GEMA. :(